# Active countdown timer - Googlesheet script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I really need your advise in my current issue.

**Background**

There is a project update that happens every Monday at 07:00 AM. This project is set up on Googlesheets. I would like to set up an active timer on Googlesheets that tells users how long left until next update.

**Problem**

If I set up a GAS code to do a countdown timer, it will only work until it reaches the time it is counting down to. What I really want is a countdown timer that restarts to the following week every time it reaches its goal. e.g. If it is now counting down till next Monday 02 April 07:00 AM, it should start counting down to 09 April 07:00 AM as soon as it hits 02 April 07:00AM....

**Solution**

So a simple solution that I thought of is setting up a simple countdown timer that does exactly what I just described in a googlesheet... simply because I am unsure how to do it in GAS..

Then using GAS I using the following code to show a toast with a countdown timer that is fetched from the Googlesheet:

```
function onOpen() {
     Utilities.sleep(1000); //initiate after 1 second from opening the sheet
     var sApp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   var Sheet = sApp.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
     var Timer = Sheet.getRange("E2").getValue(); //grabbing countdown timer set up on sheet.
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Until next update', Timer, 3000); //displaying toast for 3 seconds
     SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //flushing data when over.
      }
```

The issue is, it does not refresh... this shows me the time left since I put together the code and not actively showing me the actual time left.

**Question**

So my questions to you guys are:

(1) Why is this?

(2) Is it possible to put an active countdown timer that self restarts to the following week in GAS rather my convoluted method?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

some sheet functions behave oddly when accessed via GAS, particularly the ones that update without user input. I would recommend reporting this as a bug.

this bit of code should do what you want. I mostly used https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp to remember how dates work in JS. `the setDate()` function is very smart and will properly change the month or even year if you give it high enough or negative values. I used a switch/case statement to break the date algebra into simpler situations.

```
function onOpen(e){
var now = new Date();
  var then = new Date();
  then.setHours(7);
  then.setMinutes(0);
  switch(now.getDay()){
    case 0:
      then.setDate(then.getDate()+1);
      break;
    case 1:
      if(now.getHours()>=7){
        then.setDate(then.getDate()+7);
      }
      break;
    default:
      then.setDate(then.getDate()+8-then.getDay());
  }
  var whenwillthenbenow = Math.floor((then - now)/(1000*60*60));//msec diff to hours, adjust as necesary for days or to include fractions
       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Until next update', whenwillthenbenow + " hours", 3000); //displaying toast for 3 seconds


}
```

Parting note, from your comment i don't think `flush()` does what you think it does. It is redundant at the end of a script, or any script that executes in a couple of seconds. Mostly it is used to force updates in long scripts to make progress visible, or at particular times, such as if you were trying to do animated pixel art with cell formatting. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()